# Symfony propel:insert-sql with specified user?

Tags: php, symfony1, propel

I am running Symfony 1.3.6 on Ubuntu Lucid.

My db connections for Symfony are made with a user with reduced priveleges (no need for CREATE or DROP for example) - for security reasons.

I want to be able to run the propel task propel:sql-insert as root, so that I can create/drop tables at will. The brain dead way to do this would be to modify config/database.yml and use a root name and pwd whenever I need to run this task.

A smarter way would be if I could pass a user to the import-sql task. Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have 1.3 here; rather 1.4, but taking a look inside `lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/task/sfPropelInsertSqlTask.class.php` (phew!) yields the following parameter you can pass - presumably the same for 1.3:

> You can also use the --connection
>   option if you want to only load SQL
>   statements for a given connection.

Therefore this would imply that you can create a new connection in your `config/databases.yml` which is specific to the insert-sql task (eg username root, no password), and then pass this connection name along when you run the insert-sql task.

Untested... :-)

Comment: That's some fine spelunking there, Rich. Some mighty fine spelunking :)

Comment: Heh, I do enjoy my spelunking :-)